# I don't understand why libGLEW.so.1.10 and libGLEW.so.1.11 are required at the same time

Tags: linux, glew, shared-libraries

I didn't work during the last two months on one of my projects, today I've compiled it and I tried to run it, but when I try to run it I got this error :

`./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

so I did `ldd a.out  | grep "GLEW"` and got :

```
libGLEW.so.1.11 => /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.11 (0xb7380000)
libGLEW.so.1.10 => not found
```

locate `libGLEW` returns :

```
/usr/lib/libGLEW.so
/usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.11
/usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.11.0
/usr/lib/libGLEWmx.so
/usr/lib/libGLEWmx.so.1.11
/usr/lib/libGLEWmx.so.1.11.0
```

I don't understand why and how my project can link 1.11 and 1.10 at the same time, I check my `CMakeLists.txt` nothing specify to use 1.10 or 1.11, so from where can come from my problem ? If you need more information I can add some, but right now, I don't know what kind of informations can be usefull to fix this issue. I guess the problem appeared after an update of my OS (archlinux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the loader, these are all just file names.  It has no concept of versioning.

My guess is that the situation arose because 1.11 is a thin layer perhaps to patch a bug or enhance functionality and is suppose to mostly use the 1.10 version.

Comment: So I should still have the 1.10 version on my computer too ? but I didn't uninstall it on purpose, I only let my OS updating itself. Do you think that would mean this problem came from the updater ?

Comment: @bob-thetrashygravedigger:  If I am correct, you would need both versions installed.

Comment: ok I will try to contact the maintainer of the package (archlinux)

Comment: ok it seems the issue comes from a lib wich uses libglew 1.10. A lib compiled by myself and linked to my project... stay tuned...